# Expectation values of male-male, male-female, female-female pairs

Tags: probability

N people are seated at random to form a circle, among whom N1 are male. What are the expected numbers of male-male, male-female, and female-female nearest-neighbor pairs?

Comment: How have you tried to answer this yourself? What are you stuck on in particular?

Comment: What counts as a "nearest-neighbor pair"?

Comment: nearest-neighbor pair means two persons sitting next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Label the chairs $1$ to $N$, counterclockwise, and assume $N\gt 1$.  Let $X_i=1$ if the person in Chair $i$ is male **and** his neighbour in the **counterclockwise** direction is male. Let $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then the number $X$ of male-male nearest neighbour (unordered) pairs is given by
$$X=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_N.$$
The $E(X_i)$ are all the same. So by the linearity of expectation we have $E(X)=NE(X_1)$.

The probability that $X_1=1$ (and hence the expectation of $X_1$) is the probability the people in chairs $1$ and $2$ are both male. This probability is $\frac{N_1}{N}\cdot\frac{N_1-1}{N-1}$.

It follows that $E(X)=\frac{N_1(N_1-1)}{N-1}$.

The calculations for the other two questions are similar.

**Remark:** Alternately, one can do a Total Expectation calculation. I prefer the indicator random variable version.